# How can hide my combobox with JAvascript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have combobox which id name is option and id name  is "Chk" and my checkbox name is "chk"

and my script is look like this ;I put the script onclick but it is not work ;I check my script is loading ;I could not understand why it is not work ?Can you help me?

```
function checkAll()
{
    //do some stuff you need here

document.getElementById('option').style="none";
}

<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Chk\" value=\"Chk\" onclick=\"checkAll()\">
```

Comment: your objective is to check all checkbox elements or hide the element with id='option'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `display` property:

```
document.getElementById('option').style.display = "none";
```

This should work if you have assigned your element `id="option"`

---

If you want to check the checkbox (as function name suggests), you need to use `checked` property instead:

```
document.getElementById('option').checked = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with jquery easily.

//bind event to checkbox click

```
$(input[name=chk]).bind("click", function(e){
   //select all checkboxes based on any criteria, here on base of class
   $('.chkz').attr("checked", "checked");
   $("#option").css("display", "none");
});
```

no need to put onclick="checkall()" with that.
hop it helps,